# condition if i do not have image in blob to avoid error

Tags: php, html, cakephp

i get an error if the user does not have profile image so gives me this error:

```
` Notice: Undefined variable: type in `
Notice: Undefined variable: data in
```

but when submit an image no error found so what the solution if not submit any image to display

```
   $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blob_image WHERE user_id='".$user_data['id']."' ");
  if($q==true){
  while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
      $data=$r['image'];
      $type=$r['ext'];
          }
      echo '<img src="data:image/'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode( $data ).'"/>';}
```

Comment: `if(isset($data) && isset($type)){echo '<img src="data:image/'.$type.';base64,'.base64_encode( $data ).'"/>';}}`

Comment: using a loop to fetch what looks to only ever be a single record smells like cargo-cult programming...

Comment: Karol please take care what Marc B is saying.

Comment: @karol  please mark and up-vote the answer, as you said that it's working.thanks.

Comment: @karol  since you are not interested in marking answer as accepted even after getting answer, I am deleting my answer. Because it's wastage of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blob_image WHERE user_id='".$user_data['id']."' ");
```

if($q==true){
  while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
      $data=$r['image'];
      $type=$r['ext'];
echo '';
          }
      }

But I would suggest you take a look at PDO or MySQLi since these functions are deprecated and even removed in PHP 7